# Consecutive visited days reset randomly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I don't know why but for whatever reason the counter for how many consecutive days I have visited music.stackexchange.com gets reset randomly even though I have been on the site those days.

Currently it shows 2/30 days for the *Enthusiast* badge and this is the third time this has happened already. I know that I can't prove anything but I am 100% sure that I have visited the site on the days that the counter gets reset on (even multiple times a day). Even when I don't spend a lot of time on the site I still visit it every day to make sure the counter keeps going.

It works completely fine on StackOverflow where I am on 83/100 days. Usually after every StackOverflow visit I also come here as well, so this definitely seems to be a bug.

Comment: Has it been reset or is it stuck at 2/30? Also, are you sure you visit the site each day, according to the way the site counts the days?

Comment: It isn't stuck (now it's on 3/30) and I do visit the site every day - since there is only a two-hour difference between UTC and my timezone I'm pretty sure that there wasn't a problem with this (especially because I visit the site multiple times throughout the day). However, I just came across this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66485 that states that only visiting *homepage like sites* doesn't count as access. This seems a little odd to me because there have been times where I just visited the main page and the counter still kept going (same for SO where it's working correctly)

Comment: Are you definitely automatically (or manually) logged on every time you visit?

Comment: I'm pretty sure about that as well since I have checked the *keep me logged in* field and I can't remember the last time I had to manually log in here or on SO (and it certainly wasn't anytime between now and three days ago)

Comment: On the 5th, we have records of you only visiting the homepage. On other days (since) our records show you browsed around.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. But, does it also show what exactly I did on the 9th that counted more than just a visit. Because as I also wrote in the first comment to Dr Mayhem's answer, on that day I only visited the homepage and then left immediately to test this out. Anyways, at least I now know that visiting the homepage might or might not count so I'd better do something more to make sure :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to carry out some activities, not just visit. The definitive list of activities is not published, but voting is one.

You also have to visit within each UTC 24hr period. See [Consecutive Day count reset this morning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61007/consecutive-day-count-reset-this-morning)

My assumption is that you just visited but did nothing that counted, or that you missed the 24hr period.

Comment: This seemed to be plausible to me, so I went ahead and tested it: Yesterday, I only visited the music.stackexchange.com homepage (the general question feed) for about 4 or 5 times. I didn't do anything else other than "visiting" and immediately leaving again, without reading any question or clicking on anything. However, the counter kept going. I just checked it and it currently says 5/30. So there has to be more to this. Also it would be weird if it required more than *visiting* when the badge only says: *visit the site each day*

Comment: As I have already written in another comment: I don't think the UTC time period has anything to do with it because the UTC days start at 2am here in Germany. So if I visit the site every day at some point between 9am to 12pm german time (7am to 10pm UTC) I should be okay. And I do that muliple times a day.

Comment: Best go read that meta.se post. This has been discussed many times. The specific activity requirements are not listed, probably to avoid gaming the system

Comment: Badge descriptions also don't cover all the requirements. They are a summary, so don't assume visit means just visit. The same is true for other badges

Comment: I did already read the post and there was nothing that applied to my situation. That user only logged in once that day and since he was about 30 minutes late to the start of the new UTC day his counter got reset because he basically missed a UTC day. When I visit multiple times throughout every UTC day this should not be the case for me. Also concerning the activity requirements: My counter is still going even though I only opened and closed the site thoughout all of yesterday without any more activity.

Comment: This is tricky for me on mobile phone in foreign country with poor connectivity, but from that post I saw many in the Related sidebar that talk about this. Have a browse around.

Comment: I'll take a look at them, but most of the ones I have already seen are about the time of the visit and not about what counts as a visit and what doesn't. I'll let you know once I find anything. Thanks for your help!